# use xml file in simpleimageview setplaceholderimage

Tags: android, xml, fresco

Is there any way to use xml layout into fresco library instead of hierarchy image?
I used layout like below :

simpledraweeview.getHierarchy().setPlaceholderImage(layout.id);

but it didn't work.

this error hapend :

.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/hierarchy_layout.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the resource what you are trying to apply is not available. My Suggestion is you can try [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageView);
```

> or
>   you can try [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

```
Glide.with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fresco supports setting your placeholder in XML: http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-xml.html#_